# How do I load data into Cloudera Impala Table?

Tags: sql, uri, cloudera, impala

I'm loading data into a Cloudera Impala ODBC table using a post SQL statement but I'm getting a "URI path must be absolute" error.  Below is my SQL.

```
REFRESH sw_cfnusdata.CPN_Sales_Data;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sw_cfnusdata.CPN_Sales_Data_parquet;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sw_cfnusdata.CPN_Sales_Data_parquet LIKE
sw_cfnusdata.CPN_Sales_Data STORED AS PARQUET;
REFRESH sw_cfnusdata.CPN_Sales_Data_parquet;
LOAD DATA INPATH 'data/shared_workspace/sw_cfnusdata/Alteryx_CPN_Sales_Data' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE sw_cfnusdata.CPN_Sales_Data_parquet;
REFRESH sw_cfnusdata.CPN_Sales_Data_parquet;
COMPUTE STATS sw_cfnusdata.CPN_Sales_Data;
DROP TABLE sw_cfnusdata.CPN_Sales_Data;
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing here.  I tried the same statement without the Compute Stats function and still got the same error.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide hdfs path.

Upload that file into hdfs and try same command with hdfs path like `hdfs://DEV/data/sampletable`.

Or else you can upload the file into local disc and try below command
`load data local inpath "/data/sampletable.txt" into table sampletable;`

So, below section need to be changed and you need to add either hdfs path or local path.

```
LOAD DATA INPATH 'data/shared_workspace/sw_cfnusdata/Alteryx_CPN_Sales_Data' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE sw_cfnusdata.CPN_Sales_Data_parquet;
```